# Migrate from Firebase to NodeJs + MongoDB - Authentication and Storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am planning to migrate the backend of my app, which currently uses Firebase to a NodeJS + MongoDB server. I don't know much about Node and Mongo but I know that it is possible to export the database through a JSON file. The problem would be the login system and the files saved on Storage.

All my users can login with email and password and also by phone number. Is it possible to migrate this authentication system or do I have to start over from scratch?

Another question: is it possible to migrate data from Storage to the new server? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to migrate this authentication system or do I have to start over from scratch?

You can define users that have both an email address and a phone number and match either one when authenticating.

> is it possible to migrate data from Storage to the new server?

Yes.